# Why is the Maclaurin expansion of $\log x$ not the same as $\log (1+x)$?

Tags: logarithms, taylor-expansion

According to [this link](https://www.math24.net/power-series-expansions/) the Maclaurin expansions of $\log x$ and $\log (1+x)$ are not the same.

Could anyone provide a somewhat non-technical explanation for this? As in, why can't we use $\log (1+x)$ expansion for $ x=2 $?

Comment: You're expanding around $x=0$, the functions don't behave the same near $x=0$. As for the second thing, the series for $\log(1+x)$ around $x=0$ has a radius of convergence, outside that radius it doesn't converge. Notably it *does* converge, albeit very slowly, with $x=1$, to the actual value of $\ln(2)$.

Comment: The Maclaurin expansion of $\;\log x\;$ *does not exist* as the function isn't even defined at $\;x=0\;$ ...and the expansion of $\;\log(1+x)\;$ around $\;x=0\;$ has a convergence radius of $\;1\;$ and the interval of convergence doesn't contain its  extreme points

Comment: @donantonio: what's expression 7 in the link I provided, if the McLaurin expansion of log x doesn't exist? Also, the expansion of log(1+x) allows x=1, right? The interval only excludes $x=-1$ isn't it?

Comment: That link does not work. Is that IP address the local address of your computer? That won't work as a public link.

Comment: @PGupta (1) Your link es broken...or at least it says so in my computer, (2) The Maclaurin series of $\;\log(1+x)\;$ doesn't allow $\;x=-1\;$ for two reason: (a) as already commented, $\;\log (0)\;$ isn't defined **at all**, and (b) the Maclaurin seris of this function is the negative harmonic series, which diverges. You are right about the right extreme point, and I correct myself in this from my past comment.

Comment: I think this should work. I'll edit the post. https://www.math24.net/power-series-expansions/